# Android: Just released my app to market, but cannot purchase?

Tags: android, google-play

I finally released my application, but I get the below message when I try to purchase it.  I'm very concerned, has anyone seen this?

```
Purchase Cancelled.
Your order could not be processed.  Please try again.
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As explained [here](http://www.google.com/support/androidmarket/developer/bin/answer.py?&answer=141659), this is intentional on Google's part. I don't know the rationale for the policy, but there it is.

Comment: Sounds like a general protection against unforeseen exploits. I guess they don't see a legitimate reason to purchase your own app.

Comment: @Falmarri - I think that you're right; it's probably an abundance of caution (probably fears of abuse of the app rating system). However, as several people noted in [this other thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185846/why-i-cant-purchase-my-own-application-on-the-android-market), there are legitimate reasons to want to purchase your own app.

Answer (score 3):

Hello  ab11 and st4rdog and others,
I can verify the solution proposed by st4rdog above.  I had the same issue today, and yes this is as per Google's policy to not let people buy their own apps using the same account that you used in the Google Play Developer Console.

To get around this:

1. Go to the settings of your Android device
2. Go to accounts
3. Go to Google accounts
4. Remove the Google account that you used in the Google Play Developer Console
5. Add a new/secondary Google account (if you dont' have a second Google account, you will have to create one first).
6. Add your payment method for this Google account (i.e. credit card)
7. Go to Google Play store and buy your app!
8. Re-add your original Google account in settings -> accounts.

I wanted to experience things the way the user does when they download and install my app, so it was important to me to go through the same process.

Answer (score 1):

Add a new Google Account. Go through the process of adding the Google Wallet credit card.

Open Google Play > Settings > Account.

Change it there and you can purchase your own app to see if it works.