# How to buy my own in-App Billing product (Android)

Tags: android, in-app-billing

I'm currently testing in-app billing to activate some "pro" features in my app.
When logged in as my main gmail account though, none of it works. This is true, as the documentation says you can't buy your own stuff.

Asides from the obvious "don't use your main gmail as your developer account" answer, is there any other workaround so I can use all the pro features of my app myself without making a hacked .apk that disables license checking?

Comment: From a friends phone?

Comment: @Hackerman I'm not thinking of this in relation to testing - I have another device and a test account for that - I'm just thinking of ongoing usage. I'd like to use my own app myself on my main handset!

Comment: Aaaah, now I get it...In that case, and according to this answer, `by design` you can't purchase your own app.... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2185846/why-i-cant-purchase-my-own-application-on-the-android-market

Comment: Yeah, disappointing. I might just use a different account as my play-developer one, then I can carry on using my devices as "me"!